# PQXX linking error issue

Tags: c++, sql, mingw, libpqxx

I successfuly built PQXX for PostgreSQL. This is for Windows 7 and MinGW with the CODE::BLOCKS IDE Now after much bug hunting I have a program almost linking.  I get these three strange errors,

> fu000001.o:(.idata$2+0xc)||undefined reference to `libpqxx_a_iname'|
>
> fu000004.o:(.idata$2+0xc)||undefined reference to `libpqxx_a_iname'|
>
> nmth000000.o:(.idata$4+0x0)||undefined reference to
>   `*nm*__ZTVN4pqxx14connect_directE'|

I'm kinda at a loss here any help would be appreciated

-Roland

Comment: what platform? what compiler? what linker options?

Comment: I am also linking libpqxx.a

Comment: Check dllexport/dllimport specifiers, check library order on command lines and perhaps google (http://readlist.com/lists/lists.sourceforge.net/mingw-users/0/3102.html)

Comment: Im not using the dll just the .a file